# getting error when adding a class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a Facedtector class for my work. I added the class in my Codeigniter libraries folder and just called from my controller class. In my controller I also loaded the class but run time it is showing following error:

An Error Was Encountered

Non-existent class: FaceDetector

Please anyone can help me about this.

Thanks

Comment: please add tried code

Answer (score 0):

Add your class file inside you library folder of your main application folder.
And then you can use the auto load function of codeigniter

```
application/config/autoload.php
```

at the above location and then you can access the class directly or other way of using this use

```
$this->load->library('Your_Class_Name', 'Path\to\your\class');
```

This way you can access your class in codeigniter

You can follow below link for autoload of a class library.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html

Comment: Here is my library files like that following given bellow:namespace svay;

use Exception;

class FaceDetector
{protected $detection_data;
    protected $canvas;
    protected $face;
    private $reduced_canvas;....some functions here....

Comment: Did you followed the instruction given in the url? if yes then how your are calling your class? please let me know.

Comment: Yea I added the file in libraries folder and and autoloader also.Now I am calling the files using ,this->load->library('Your_Class_Name') from my controller. But still same errors showing.

Comment: First of all if you have added the library in autoload array then again you dont have to call the library like this $this->load->library('Your_Class_Name', 'Path\to\your\class'); Call your class directly because codeigniter autoloader has already intiated the class now you have to directly call your class and their function like Your_Class_Name->functionName(params); This will give you the result.

Comment: Yea , now I have added the file in autoload just and the calling function controller is also not loading before calling. When the page is loading it gives same error.

Comment: Is your class file name and class name is same?

Comment: yea,But before class declaring class they used like that : namespace svay;

use Exception;

class FaceDetector
{

    protected $detection_data;
    protected $canvas;
    protected $face;
    private $reduced_canvas;

Comment: You have to change this to public class otherwise it will not be accessible